# Raspberry pi connection trouble

Tags: pi-2

When I try to connect my raspberry pi to my laptop via Ethernet, it is not assigning any dynamic IP to my laptop(windows 10) though my laptop is set to obtain dynamic IP. I didn't even make the IP static for pi when it was working.

What to do?

Comment: What to do is give a little more information on your network setup, because this question is very broad at the moment.

Comment: Connecting pi and laptop directly via Ethernet cable.

Comment: Using dhcp or static configuration?

Comment: using DHCP here

Comment: Do you have the DHCP **service** running on your laptop?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the RPi or the laptop to obtain an IP address by DHCP, it needs to be attached to a DHCP server. Normally, your router provides this service.

Have you installed a DHCP server on your RPi? If not, then the RPi cannot assign the laptop an IP address. I'm not suggesting this as a solution; only an illustration that you can't serve DHCP without a DHCP server.

Assuming you don't have access to a router, here's a guide to making a direct connection between the RPi and the laptop: https://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/